# CF5 cfhttp timeout on shared server

Tags: coldfusion

Unbelieveably I have a client still on ColdFusion 5. Website has the following line of code which fetches booking related data.

```
<cfhttp url="#WunServer#/GetBookingRatesForOwner.cfm" method="POST" 
resolveurl="false" timeout="20" throwonerror="yes">
      <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="ListOwnerID" value="#ListOwnerID#">
      <cfhttpparam type="FORMFIELD" name="RATESCATEGORYID" value="3,1">
</cfhttp>
```

We are periodically getting an error message:

> The time taken to process your request has exceeded the allowable
>   limit of 30 seconds. Please notify the server administrator (using the
>   mail link below) that this error has occurred.

The error happens generally when site is accessed from overseas. There is a bottleneck in the system which I can't go into detail about here, but which we intend to resolve.

So, evidently the shared coldfusion hosting server has a timeout setting of 30 seconds, which overrode the cfhttp timeout setting of 20 seconds. We cannot change the shared server setting. But, we want to increase the timeout value and see if this persistent error disappears or lessens. Remembering this is CF5, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Two things are strange in this question.  One is that part of the url is a variable.  The other is that a 30 second timeout overriding a 20 second timeout actually presents a problem.

Comment: Not strange to have a variable. It resolves to a different server, which is set in application.cfm. It's not the fact that 30 seconds overrides 20 seconds is a problem. Issue is how, without access to CFAdmin on a shared hosting server, does one increase the timeout setting above 30 seconds in ColdFusion5. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: The section called 'Migration note from ColdFusion 5 to ColdFusion MX' at http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-mx-explanation-request-timeout.html suggests you can use a URL parameter called RequestTimeout in ColdFusion 5 to set a custom request timeout for the current request.